# Could I download GTA V and play it without the disc?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My disc drive doesn't work on my xbox anymore, but if I download the game from the marketplace, is it possible to bypass using the disc and ONLY play the downloaded version?

Comment: Yes, that's what the download version of a game is for. What you *really* should be asking is: `Can I use my saves from the retail version with the download version, or will I need to start a new save?` Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to this particular question.

Comment: The reason I asked that was because I downloaded GTA IV EFLC and it said I needed the disc in order to access the data.

Comment: @PatrickBurke you should report that to microsoft. If you paid for Episodes from liberty city (I'm assuming this specifically holds all DLC and Full game), then you should've gotten the full game.

Comment: @Nolonar Yes, the saves should be pulled from the same hard drive as the locations of the saves should be recognized. If there is no save it may place you into a new game, in that case open the load game menu and change your device to the device with the saves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Downloading a game will NOT require the disc to be in the drive as you have paid for the license.

This is because of the fact that Microsoft is still selling the license for the disc. This was their plan with the Xbox One and allowing for "Steam-like" usability (log in anywhere and be able to play the game)

I.E. I pay for the digital version = I wont receive the disc but for as long as that file remains on the server, I will have access to it and be able to play it without having to mess with inserting stuff in the drive.

In regards to save files on downloaded games, They are stored in YOUR CHOSEN SAVE DESTINATION. Just be sure to save in the same place and the game **SHOULD** see the save.